# mysql dump file missing table structures and data

Tags: mysql, database, my.cnf, table-structure

I'm running the following command in mysql to dump a database:

```
mysqldump --login-path=bc --single-transaction --routines my_database > /tmp/my_database
```

The dump file that is generated only contains variables, and no table structures and data.

```
- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.49-89.0, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: my_host    Database: my_database
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.35-38-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'my_database'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2021-09-23 12:28:51
~
```

My co-worker runs the same command on the same host, but his dump file is drastically different. It includes the same SET variables as my file, but also:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `table_1`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_1`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `autoinc` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   ... primary key stuff
   ... unique key stuff
   ... constraints
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table_1`
--

LOCK TABLES `table_1` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_1` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_1` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

... etc
```

I was reading up on the my.cnf file, which I do have in /etc/, but nothing in that file differs from my co-workers. I'm very confused as to how we have such different dump files - running the same commands, on the same host, with the same my.cnf file.

Any direction on what to do / try next is appreciated. This is as far as I've gotten. Could it be something other than the my.cnf file? Permissions based?

I don't want to try a new command, because that would require a re-write of a bunch of unit tests in Perl that integrate with mysql. My goal is to figure out what is causing my dump file specifically to leave out the structures and data.

Comment: Different users logged into the same host. Is it possible that this is permissions based? If so, how might I check?

Comment: It's the mysql user that matters, not necessarily the Linux user. Try each of you connecting to the original database from which you created the dump file, using the [mysql command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), and then run `SHOW GRANTS;`